# Accessing template variables from outside PHPBB

Tags: php, templates, phpbb

)
I'm developing a website and I want to use PHPBB auth system. I managed to get it working pretty well, following a few suggestions I found on this website, but I've got a problem.
Basically all I need to do is accessing template variables such as {U_PROFILE}, {L_PROFILE}, {U_PRIVATEMSGS}, {PRIVATE_MESSAGE_INFO} and others, from outside PHPBB.
Is this possible?
The page where is need to echo those variables already has those lines of code:

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
define('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH', "./board/");
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template variables are set by the PHP scripts that use the templates. So they are not really separate from the PhpBB code.

But the templates variables you mention are available in include/page_header.php so you could also try to incorporate that file in your script and build your own page the same way as is done in the Phpbb code.